# XCode: Change xcarchive folder and file name

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm generating the .xcarchive file from the command line, using:

```
xcodebuild -scheme fullxsTest archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

This puts the file in...

```
/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-09-12/App 10-09-12 13.45.xcarchive
```

... which is unfortunate since I would like to upload the file to a server and would like to **specify a custom directory and file name for the .xcarchive file.**

I tried the Locations in XCode Preferences, but it still places the file in a time stamped folder with a time stamped file name.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you upload from the archive directory, perhaps deleting all archives first so you use the right version?

Comment: Actually I can, I just didn't think it through :) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to extract the path and name of the file even if they are auto-generated with the following few lines:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:BUILD_DIR_ROOT error:nil];
NSString *archiveDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",BUILD_DIR_ROOT,[dirContents lastObject]];
NSArray *arcContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:archiveDir error:nil];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",BUILD_DIR_ROOT,[dirContents lastObject],[arcContents lastObject]];
```

After this I check that the returned value is not the automatically created hidden .DS_Store file and if it's not, then I'm good to go.